# Searching for a string within the result of RegEx in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, search, innerhtml, indexof

Very weird behaviour in the below code:

```
var showContent = document.getElementById("something"); // Search for a content
showContent = showContent.innerHTML;
var patt3=/Profile">[^<]*(?=<)/; // Search for this pattern ...
var showName=patt3.exec(showContent); // ... within the above found content
```

The problem begins when I want to search for a string within the result of the above showName:

```
var yesTest = showName.indexOf("text");
alert(yesTest);
```

The above always returns -1 (the content is not found). However, this

```
alert(showName);
```

clearly does have "text" in it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use this pattern: `/Profile">([^<]*)(?=<)/`. Then, `showName = patt3.exec(showContent);showName=showName ? showName[1] : '';showName.indexOf('text');`. Why? Because, in your case, `indexOf` will not start at zero, and might include `Profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.exec` returns an array, not a string.  Doing `.indexOf` on an array will return the array element index that equals your search term in full (or fail in browsers that don't recognize it e.g. IE8).

You can do `showName.toString().indexOf("text")` if that's what you want.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but I couldn't find anything saying that `.exec` doesn't return a string. It now works. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z908hy33(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

try like this :

```
var patt3=/Profile">[^<]*(?=<)/;

 var re = new RegExp(regexp);

 re.test(showContent );
```

test will return true or false